# Duplicated top header using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm starting this little project with three tabs.

The title is showing correctly on each one of the tab items, but the header is duplicated on the views.

If I put the below code in the screen, the duplicated header is gone, but the title is not showing anymore.

```
static navigationOptions = {
header: null,
};
```

If I put this code, the title is not shown, the title is only showing when I put the title on creation of the createStackNavigator.

```
static navigationOptions = {
title:  'Some Title'
};
```

Here is the full code and some screenshots of the problem.

Code: https://gist.github.com/alanPTK/7c3de2d7cecea38cf64df1525fd6b3d2

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dybgJ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

```js
headerMode: 'none',
navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
}
```

in your StackNavigators navigationOptions, it will remove the top header which will leave the bottom header on each screen, so you can set title on each screen with

```js
static navigationOptions = {
   title: "Your title"
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, still showing the duplicated header.   
Here's the [updated code](https://gist.github.com/alanPTK/e0de04f26e393c716dd3ae0036c6231c)
and a [screenshot] (https://imgur.com/a/6btRvm0)

Comment: Try setting `navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
}` inside of createBottomTabNavigator

Comment: It didn't work also. I did like this

[code](https://gist.github.com/alanPTK/1ee7a33d52f8e6582ed2651f76597a2f)

Comment: Ok, give me some time I'll take a deeper look.

Comment: Here's the full source code: [source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UXXY2H6VvwV4P9JEUNNBrdjM7DHjc8VI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Ok so in your `routes.js`, inside of NavigationStack, add `{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
 }` this will disable the top header

Comment: If it doesnt work please include package.json with the source code so I can run it myself

Comment: No problem! I will change the answer a bit :D